# Time does not echo right

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone know this this code echos 
"Banned on February 2th, 6:09:06pm, Until March 3rd, 6:09:06am"
instead of 
"Banned on February 28th, 6:09:06pm, Until March 1st, 6:09:06am"

```
$BanDate = date("F nS, g:i:sa", $other['BanTime'] + 3600);
$BanDateK = date("F nS, g:i:sa", $other['BanTimeK'] + 3600);
if($other['BanTime'] == "life"){
echo"<center>R.I.P. ".$other['Username'].", Banned on ".$BanDateK."</center>";
} elseif($other['BanTime'] >= time()){
echo"<center>Banned on ".$BanDateK.", Until ".$BanDate."</center>";
}
```

The time in the database looks like "1362308946".

Comment: n = `Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros` you want j = `Day of the month without leading zeros`

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing how you are setting `$other['BanTime']` and `$other['BanTimeK']`. Are you sure the system date of the server is correct?

Comment: elaborating a better question (maybe narrowing down the problem before posting) is generally a good idea and helps getting better answers (:

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that the value of `$other['BanTimeK'] + 3600` corresponds to the day February 2nd...

Since I tried and the `1362308946` corresponds to March 3rd.

Double-check the value of `$other['BanTimeK']` and if that does not solve it, tell us more about it.

Comment: The first answer fixed it.